# C# Graphics Programming on OS

Tags: c#, .net, mono

This is an odd question.  I am interested in building an application for navigation on the computer.  I want to give the user "physical cues" when they accomplish something.  For instance, a white halo expanding when a folder is clicked.  Can this be done with C#.  One user suggested I expand this with more detail to be more specific.  I want to use the Kinect to allow the user to navigate through the OS.  However, I want them to be able to use both hands so I don't want to just attach the hand to the mouse pointer.  I would like to give the user some visual feedback on their interaction with the OS.  I am having trouble thinking of the best way to do this.  So I want to create visual effects on the OS, but not in any specific window like a game window.

Most of the graphic tutorials I see either involve building a window and rendering pipeline for that window; or using WPF and Silverlight graphics and animations.  I need more flexibility then that because this will be for the OS and not for a particular application.  I'm having trouble figuring out where to start and if it is even possible using .NET or the Mono Framework.

Am I better off just using C++ to accomplish this goal.  Please let me know if this is too open ended of a question.  I am trying to find how to start going about something like this.  Thanks!

Comment: This is a very general question. I think you will need to give examples and pad this out somewhat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.NET WinForms, like C++ WinForms use GDI+, .NET is just more abstracted. You still have access to native code via p/invoke and the ability to override protected members in the abstracted BCL meaning you still have a fair level of control. So unless you're talking about a specific graphics library I don't think .NET WinForms are lesser than C++. in this context.

Regarding your task I would research layered windows. Sorry, I don't have any comprehensive references handy as I strugled to find them when I was learning but here's a class I mustered together that could help you get started with drawing on a [Layered Window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997507.aspx). Rather than deriving your Main form from `Form` derive from `SingleLayeredForm`:

```
public class SingleLayeredForm : Form
{
    public new event PaintEventHandler Paint;

    public SingleLayeredForm()
    {
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
        this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
    }

    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            if (DesignMode) return base.CreateParams;
            CreateParams createParams = base.CreateParams;
            createParams.ExStyle = createParams.ExStyle | 0x80000;
            return createParams;
        }
    }

    public void SetBitmap(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        if (!IsHandleCreated || DesignMode) return;
        IntPtr oldBits = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr screenDC = WinAPI.GetDC(IntPtr.Zero);
        IntPtr hBitmap = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr memDC = WinAPI.CreateCompatibleDC(screenDC);
        try
        {
            Point topLocation = new Point(this.Left, this.Top);
            Size bitmapSize = new Size(bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);
            WinAPI.BLENDFUNCTION blendFunc = new WinAPI.BLENDFUNCTION();
            Point sourceLocation = Point.Empty;
            hBitmap = bitmap.GetHbitmap(Color.FromArgb(0));
            oldBits = WinAPI.SelectObject(memDC, hBitmap);

            blendFunc.BlendOp = WinAPI.AC_SRC_OVER;
            blendFunc.SourceConstantAlpha = 255;
            blendFunc.AlphaFormat = WinAPI.AC_SRC_ALPHA;
            blendFunc.BlendFlags = 0;

            WinAPI.UpdateLayeredWindow(Handle, screenDC, ref topLocation, ref bitmapSize, memDC, ref sourceLocation, 0, ref blendFunc, WinAPI.ULW_ALPHA);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (hBitmap != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                WinAPI.SelectObject(memDC, oldBits);
                WinAPI.DeleteObject(hBitmap);
            }
            WinAPI.ReleaseDC(IntPtr.Zero, screenDC);
            WinAPI.DeleteDC(memDC);
        }
    }

    public new void Invalidate()
    {
        using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(this.ClientSize.Width, this.ClientSize.Height))
        {
            using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
            {

                graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighSpeed;
                graphics.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceCopy;

                if (this.Paint != null)
                    this.Paint(this, new PaintEventArgs(graphics, Rectangle.Empty));
            }
            SetBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
}

public sealed class WinAPI
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool HideCaret(IntPtr hWnd);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
    public static extern short GetKeyState(int keyCode);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, uint fsModifiers, uint vk);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool UnregisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id);

    [DllImport("gdi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr CreateCompatibleDC(IntPtr hdc);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetDC(IntPtr hWnd);

    [DllImport("gdi32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, PreserveSig = true, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr SelectObject(IntPtr hdc, IntPtr hgdiobj);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool ReleaseDC(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hDC);

    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    public static extern bool DeleteDC(IntPtr hdc);

    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    public static extern bool DeleteObject(IntPtr hObject);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool UpdateLayeredWindow(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr hdcDst, ref Point pptDst, ref Size psize, IntPtr hdcSrc, ref Point pptSrc, uint crKey, [In] ref BLENDFUNCTION pblend, uint dwFlags);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetDesktopWindow();

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetWindowDC(IntPtr ptr);

    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr CreateCompatibleBitmap(IntPtr hdc, int nWidth, int nHeight);

    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    public static extern bool BitBlt(IntPtr hdcDest, int xDest, int yDest, int wDest, int hDest, IntPtr hdcSource, int xSrc, int ySrc, CopyPixelOperation rop);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, out RECT rect);

    public const byte AC_SRC_OVER = 0;
    public const byte AC_SRC_ALPHA = 1;
    public const byte ULW_ALPHA = 2;

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
    public struct BLENDFUNCTION
    {
        public byte BlendOp;
        public byte BlendFlags;
        public byte SourceConstantAlpha;
        public byte AlphaFormat;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct RECT
    {
        public int Left;
        public int Top;
        public int Right;
        public int Bottom;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you!  This is definitely uncharted territory for me.  I will research pinvoke and the example above.  I appreciate the help.  I will upvote when I have enough reputation points to do so.